# Passing two Models in update view to a same template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I want to render two models `User` (built in model) and `Profile` model to the same template `profile_form.html` so that the user can update the data of both `User` model as well as `Profile` model

This is my `Profile` model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='profile_pics')
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + "'s Profile"
```

This is my `profile_form.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}
    Make your Profile
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container mb-6">
    <form action="" method="POST" class="form-group">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

This is my `UserUpdateView`

```
class UserUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model=User
    fields=['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']
    success_url='/'

    def test_func(self):
        x = self.request.user.id
        y = self.kwargs['pk']
        if x == y:
            return True
        else:
            if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
                raise Http404("You are not authenticated to edit this profile")
```

I want my `Profile` model's to be below `User` model's form

Please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

To add a OneToOne-relation into the same view, you just need to overwrite the get_context_data method and provide an additional form.
If you don't have a profile form yet, just create a simple one:

```
#yourapp/forms.py
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = "__all__"
```

Now, to use this in your updateview, import it and you will need to change it like this:

```
class UserUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model=User
    fields=['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']
    success_url='/'

    # create context manually
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(UserUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data["profile"] = ProfileForm(self.request.POST)
        else:
            # accessing the profile object
            data["profile"] = ProfileForm(instance=self.object.profile)
        return data
```

And now your template will have access to the context profile

```
...
{{ form|crispy }}
{{ profile|crispy }}
...
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Also note that this will fail in case the profile is optional or null (but with your user model it won’t happen). Please also remember to mark your questions as answered or upvote helpful answers.